# How to change MARQUEE_RESTART_DELAY time of marquee inner class of TextView android

Tags: android, textview, marquee

I have added marquee  in TextView and its working fine but it give some delay to restart again while scrolling .

I dig up TextView class as well and find

```
      private static final MARQUEE_DELAY =1200;
      private static final MARQUEE_RESTART_DELAY =1200;
```

Please help me to change MARQUEE_DELAY or MARQUEE_RESTART_DELAY time dynamically ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this using the **Java Reflection API**.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301635/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection) for more info.

**OR**

Make sure to either set the **TextView** gravity to `Gravity.LEFT` or `Gravity.CENTER`.